# GraphStore and Datasets in SPARQL Update 1.1

Tags: sparql

According to SPARQL Update 1.1. "A Graph Store is a mutable container of RDF graphs managed by a single service.". I was wondering if a GraphStore (in SPARQL Update) is the same with an RDF Dataset (in SPARQL Query). Or a GraphStore is a container of RDF Datasets.And if so, then what happening with the default graph that must be unique.

Answer (score 2):

An RDF Dataset is an immutable thing - it's a value and you can't change. c.f. 1

A Graph Store is like a programming language set - it's mutable.

Comment: Yes, but is there a relationship between a Graphstore and a Dataset?